# Magnified UI for the whole ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, xcode6

I dont quite remember what change I made but the whole UI seemed to be magnified for my ios app including font sizes , image sizes. Strange thing is the time  , battery power ad network connection symbols which are usually shown on top have also magnified. I cant seem to figure out why . Can someone please advise ?

I have already tried playing with size classes ( with / without for each VC ) and it dint work

Comment: Does this occur only on simulators or physical devices as well?

Comment: It occurs on simulators and physical devices as well

Answer (score 0):

It may be running in the 4" compatibility mode, which was to allow older apps to run on the newer 6 and 6+ phones full screen. you might need to change your splash screen of you app to have all the sizes to fix this, if you dont have it already

Comment: deleted and added splash screen but there is no option to change font size on it :( (   issue still persists)